# Can I get advice on my nginx configuration (as a proxy in front of Jira and Confluence)?

Tags: linux, nginx, confluence, jira

I was wondering if I could get some advice on my nginx configuration.  The config seems to be working, but I'm unsure if I'm doing everything properly.  The basic idea is to have a Jira and Confluence server (in separate Tomcat instances) running on the same machine, with nginx in front to handle SSL for both.  I want only SSL connections to be made to Jira/Confluence.  Jira is running on 127.0.0.1:9090 and Confluence on 127.0.0.1:8080.  Here is my nginx.conf, any advice or tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
user              nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log         /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid               /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request '
                      '"$status" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    # Our self-signed cert
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/fissl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/fissl.key;

    # redirect non-ssl Confluence to ssl
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  confluence.example.com;
        rewrite ^(.*) https://confluence.example.com$1 permanent;
    }

    # redirect non-ssl Jira to ssl
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  jira.example.com;
        rewrite ^(.*) https://jira.example.com$1 permanent;
    }

    #
    # The Confluence server
    #
    server {
        listen       443;
        server_name  confluence.example.com;

        ssl on;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/confluence.access.log  main;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/confluence.error.log;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  https;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;            
        }

        error_page  404              /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
           root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
           root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

    }

    #
    # The Jira server
    #
    server {
        listen       443;
        server_name  jira.example.com;

        ssl on;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/jira.access.log  main;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/jira.error.log;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9090/;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  https;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }

        error_page  404              /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine, but, you'd probably get better performance if you served static files (images, css etc.) directly fron nginx rather than proxying it to tomcat.

Comment: and moved nginx to it's own hardware, thus offloading ssl to separate cpu.